# Space after span tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tags, spacing

I always thought that in HTML the spacing of the tags didn't affect the content of the code. In this example, however, I found the content to be affected by spaces.

```
<h4><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"> Vaccinations</span> </h4>
```

In this case, if I remove the space after the opening span tag, the Bootstrap Glyphicon is pressed against the "Vaccinations" header.However, if I add the space, a space appears between the Glyphicon and the "Vaccinations" header. Why does this happen?

Comment: Any screenshots to share?

Comment: Because a space is a character. However, many spaces are condensed into one except when in a `pre` tag.

Comment: Inline element are sensitive to spaces.

Comment: In HTML, whitespace is typically reduced to a single character. I'm not sure where you got the idea that it gets stripped, but you're mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces in element content are just character data and get inserted into the element content in the internal representation (DOM). So spaces are relevant, though they may get ignored in rendering under certain conditions.

In particular, a space at the start of a line is ignored; it does not cause spacing. But here the page uses Twitter [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) techniques for inserting icons at the start of element content. Those techniques add a code point (Private Use “character”) using the `:before` pseudo-element in CSS and use CSS rules to make that code point rendered as a special glyph. This means that when the `span` element is rendered, its content begins with that code point, as “generated content”, followed by the content in HTML markup. So if there is a space in HTML markup, it will be treated as a word space here, instead of being at the start of a line.

This can be illustrated with a simpler setup, where I used the real character “X” as the generated content:

```
<style>
div:before { content: "X" }
</style>
<div>foo</div>
<div> foo</div>
```

This causes the renderings “Xfoo” and “X foo”,

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Glyphicon classes incorrectly. Per [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use), emphasis added:

> ## Only for use on empty elements
>
> Icon classes should only be used on elements that **contain no text content** and have **no child elements**.

Which is to say that your "Vaccinations" text should NOT be within the `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin">` .